# module 'tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist' has no attribute 'x_train'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I tried to print the values of x_tain, x_test, y_train, y_test after downloading the MNIST dataset and loading it into the respective variables. and then it's showing me this error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print("No of labels in training set {}".format(mnist.y_train.labels.shape))
print("No of images in test set {}".format(mnist.x_test.images.shape))
print("No of labels in test set {}".format(mnist.y_test.labels.shape))
print("No of images in training set {}".format(mnist.x_train.images.shape))
```

after executing it's showing the following error
`module 'tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist' has no attribute 'x_train'`

Comment: Does it work if you put another pair of parentheses? `((x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test))`

Comment: tensorflow version please

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary quotes from your code lines.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.dataset.mnist` has only one method, it's `load_data()` according to [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/mnist.py#L27-L67) and it returns two tuples :`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`. To check their shape:

```
x_train.shape
y_train.shape
x_test.shape
y_test.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.datasets.mnist` module indeed does not have any other members other than `load_data`. So adding a module name `mnist` everywhere before loaded values does not make sense. You loaded your data as `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`  and they are available to you as such. There is no need for `mnist.y_train`, just use `y_train`